# Cannot log after tests are done. - Jest / Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am writing a simple application that I need to return a value, but I NEED to print in the console the result.

```
const knowYourCustomer = async (body: Body): Promise<kycResponse> => {
  validator(body)
  const applicationKey = process.env.APIKEY
  const kyc = await axios.post('https://xxxx', body, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${applicationKey}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  return kyc.data
}


const knowYourCustomerParser = (data: kycResponse): object => {
  const verificationCode = data.verificationResultCode;
  if (verificationCode === 'Y') {
    return {
      kycResult: true
    }
  } else if (verificationCode === 'N') {
    return {
      kycResult: false
    }
  }
  return {
    code: verificationCode,
    message: verificationCode === 'D' ? 'Document Error' : 'Server Error'
  }
}


(async () => {
  try {
    const data = await knowYourCustomer(body)
    const response = knowYourCustomerParser(data)
    console.log(response)
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})()
```

So i created a jest test to test the function knowYourCustomer

```
import { knowYourCustomer } from '../../src';

describe("knowYourCustomer response paser", () => {
  it("should return verificationCode propertie", async () => {
    const body = {
      birthDate: "1985-02-08",
      givenName: "James",
    }
  
    const response = await knowYourCustomer(body)
    expect(response).toHaveProperty('verificationResultCode')
  });
});
```

When I run test, the test pass, but i receive a message  :
Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?

I tried to change async await for the test, for the function, but nothing changes..
How ca I fix this error/warningty

Comment: You have an IIFE that runs when the module is imported. That's very difficult to test. Consider breaking it out into a separate module instead.

Comment: it worked .. thanks!